# Sandcastle how to include subtopics in TOC

Tags: sandcastle

I'm just getting started with Sandcastle, trying to build a conceptual help file without any code component at all. I've got a basic framework working, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get things into the Table of contents. As I understand it the TOC is based on the contents of the Content Layout.content file, but all I can add are FILES not links within a file.

Is there some syntax that will allow me to have a section within a file appear as a TOC entry? I'm working with some AML files provided by a client, and they include lots of tags that look like this:

```
<section address="_Toc190084020">
```

but the _Toc is apparently meaningless, because they don't appear anywhere.

cheers,

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this same question on the SHFB website (https://shfb.codeplex.com/discussions) and got an answer from Eric Woodruff, the maintainer of the project.

It turns out that the table of contents is based strictly on the files included in the project, so the only way to get more TOC entries is to break it into more files.